# Why are set timeouts invalidated by a page reload and how to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, reload

I have a website which I automatically navigate on a loop using Javascript to imitate a user's actions.

For the cases when something goes wrong and the loop stops working, I have a failsafe mechanism. On each iteration the following code is executed:

```
var failsafe = function () {
    console.log("Something went wrong, reloading...");

    window.location.reload();
    document.failsafeTimeout = setTimeout(failsafe, 60000);
};

if (document.failsafeTimeout !== undefined) {
    // the previous iteration went fine, clearing the old timeout

    clearTimeout(document.failsafeTimeout);
}

document.failsafeTimeout = setTimeout(failsafe, 60000);
```

The problem is, the code doesn't work as I expect. When the loop breaks, the failsafe handler is called once, but, despite being set again, is never called again. After the failsafe handler finishes executing, `document.failsafeTimeout` is `undefined`. I assume that `window.location.reload()` works asynchronously, which destroys the `failsafeTimeout` property after it's been assigned.

How do I rewrite the failsafe timeout handler so that it could set a new timeout which would survive the page reload?

Comment: location.reload() entirely reloads the page, which breaks any javascript invocation. You can still have a bit of code running in the onunload event, but don't expect code to persist between sessions (or you have to serialize data in cookies or localStorage beforehand)

Comment: @RegisPortalez, yeah, that explains everything, thank you.

Comment: made an answer from my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

window.location.reload() entirely reloads the page, which breaks any javascript invocation.

You can still have a bit of code running by listening the [onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) event, but don't expect code to persist between sessions (or you have to serialize data in cookies or localStorage beforehand)