# DOM of new page inaccessible after window.location.href value changes

Tags: javascript

I've a rating submission form. In `form.onSubmit()`, I capture the rating data, redirect to a "thank you page" with `window.location.replace(url)`.

I'm trying to append the rating data in the new page. However, once the page is replaced, I can access the formData variable, but, DOM of the new page seems inaccessible.

Code:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(form);

  window.location.replace('thankyou.html');

  console.log(formData.get('rating'));
  
  // dom not accessible after replace
  console.log(document.body);
}
```

Any leads?

Comment: I believe it's for security so that malicious code on one page can't do something after navigating to another page

Comment: JavaScript acts on one page only. You'd have to load your script on the new page as well.

Comment: What do you think `window.location.replace('thankyou.html')` does? Because as written, it will immediately kick in, and the browser will throw everything from the current page away in order to load the new URL you told it to load.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the variables, e.g. formData, are still accessible. Is the script invalidated after the function ends?

Comment: Save your data in sessionStorage, navigate to the new page, and in JavaScript on that new page - load the data from sessionStorage.

Comment: @SumanjitSengupta the function never even "ends", the moment you change the URL the browser invalidates anything from the now-previous-URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future ref., it seems all content and attached resources are removed on page reload/redirect.

Another similar query: [set timeouts invalidated by page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142970/why-are-set-timeouts-invalidated-by-a-page-reload-and-how-to-avoid-it)

Resources:
[MDN window event - unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload)